# Why is rasa init resulting in no module named past, but the future library is installed properly?

Tags: python, module, integration, chatbot, rasa

I’m trying to create a rasa chatbot with rasa init, and am opting into the initial training. I have no idea where this error message is coming from: the future library is installed properly and I have uninstalled and reinstalled it but this error persists. I am using Python 3.9.13 and a venv.

```
Finished creating project structure.
? Do you want to train an initial model?  Yes
Training an initial model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\ayu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\Scripts\rasa.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\__main__.py", line 133, in main
    cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 238, in run
    init_project(args, path)
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 132, in init_project
    print_train_or_instructions(args)
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 64, in print_train_or_instructions
    training_result = rasa.train(
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\api.py", line 103, in train
    from rasa.model_training import train
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\model_training.py", line 7, in <module>
    import rasa.engine.validation
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\engine\validation.py", line 33, in <module>
    from rasa.engine.constants import RESERVED_PLACEHOLDERS
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\engine\constants.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rasa.core.channels import UserMessage
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from rasa.core.channels.webexteams import WebexTeamsInput
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\webexteams.py", line 7, in <module>
    from webexteamssdk import WebexTeamsAPI, Webhook
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\webexteamssdk\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .api import WebexTeamsAPI
  File "C:\Users\ayu\chat\lib\site-packages\webexteamssdk\api\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from past.types import basestring
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'past'
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled future already, and am at a lost as to what could be causing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community The only "code" I've written outside of this is rasa init.